Typehint *args for variable length heterogenous return values like asyncio.gather()
I'm having some trouble with the typesystem here.
I need something like asyncio.gather() where the return value is the return values of the coroutines in the same order as given in the args.
async def f1() -> int: ...
async def f2() -> str: ...
async def f3() -> bool: ...

a, b, c = await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2(), f3())

This works:

a is of type int
b is of type str
c is of type bool

I have a function that accepts multiple partial[Coroutine[Any, Any, T]].
type PartialCoroutine[T] = partial[Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]

async def run runPartialCoroutines[T](*args: PartialCoroutine[T]) -> list[T]: ...

If I run my function it only uses the return value of the first function
async def f1() -> int: ...
async def f2() -> str: ...
async def f3() -> bool: ...

a, b, c = await runPartialCoroutines(f1(), f2(), f3())

This doesn't work:

a is of type int
b is of type int
c is of type int

I understand why it does this, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work.
I've checked the typehint of asyncio.gather() but I have a feeling that the typecheckers have some custom logic built in for this case.
Is it possible to do this at all?

While battling out similar cases, I found out that just writing out runPartialCoroutines(a1: PartialCoroutine[T1], a2: PartialCoroutine[T2], a3: PartialCoroutine[T3]) -> Tuple[T1, T2, T3]: ... is the simplest and most more reliable.

This question is similar to: Using TypeVarTuple with inner TypeVar (variadic generics transformation). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answer isn't pretty. Basically, typeshed provides a bunch of overloads for up to 6 arguments, so that static type checkers can make the correct inferences.
@overload
def gather(coro_or_future1: _FutureLike[_T1], /, *, return_exceptions: Literal[False] = False) -> Future[tuple[_T1]]: ...  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
@overload
def gather(  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
    coro_or_future1: _FutureLike[_T1], coro_or_future2: _FutureLike[_T2], /, *, return_exceptions: Literal[False] = False
) -> Future[tuple[_T1, _T2]]: ...
@overload
def gather(  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
    coro_or_future1: _FutureLike[_T1],
    coro_or_future2: _FutureLike[_T2],
    coro_or_future3: _FutureLike[_T3],
    /,
    *,
    return_exceptions: Literal[False] = False,
) -> Future[tuple[_T1, _T2, _T3]]: ...
...


It's not possible. asyncio.gather is type-hinted with 14 separate overloads (or 13 on the pre-Python 3.10 side) to try to cover most calls, and even then, the hints still have to lie about the return type - the function actually returns a list, but the hints pretend it returns a tuple, because lists can't have individual element types annotated separately.
